# excel vba sql server data import "type mismatch error"

Tags: sql, excel, vba, import

I am attempting to create a macro that will pull in some data into Excel 2003 from SQL Server 2005.

The SQL code is in this macro, and part of the code for this comes from values in a cell in Excel. This works, to a degree, but when the data in the Excel cell that i'm using for the SQL code exceeds a line in the formula preview (or approx 170 characters), i get the "Type mismatch" error. Otherwise it works correctly.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array( _
"OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data       Source=anglobisql;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto " _
    , _
    "Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=MyIDHere;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=F" _
    , "alse;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME"), Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLENAME (nolock) WHERE COLUMN1 IN (" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("e607").Value & ")")
    .Name = "DATABASE TABLENAME"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceConnectionFile = _
    "H:\My Data Sources\DATABASE TABLENAME.odc"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Obviously all databasename and tablename are filled in correctly.

Any idea why this is falling down (whether there's a character limit, or whether it fails because the cell value continues onto the next line in the formula preview bar in Excel? How could this be fixed?

Much appreciated,

Alex

Comment: 32,767 characters is the limit for an Excel Cell. My guess is that all your data is inserted in a single Cell (A1).

Comment: Not quite sure whether you're referring to the input or the output.

For output: When the sql query works properly data comes through in different cells, so this isn't an issue 

For input: the cut-off seems to be about 170 characters, so again 32,767 not an issue.

Comment: I can see that there does appear to be a text limit in the "Command Text" of "Edit OLE DB Query" within Excel, but again i think i'm well within it.

Comment: What is the data in Cell E607? (Format, special caracters, ...?). It should look like "SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA .."

Comment: it's just the customised SQL code, in this case a list of numbers

so select colA, colB where colA IN (602023, 45023, 230203, 230203) from tableA.

Again, there's no real issue with the code until the cell reaches a certain size

Comment: Try that --> .CommandText = String instead of Array

Comment: Solved it! Didnt work changing it to string so I just took out the "array" part of that code and it works perfectly!

Comment: Thats actually what I meant by using String type ("SELECT...") instead of Array Type (Array("SELECT ...")). Glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problems caused by the Excel cell having more than 170 characters. I suggest splitting the line that errors out to help find exactly where the problem is.

Replace this:

```
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLENAME (nolock) WHERE COLUMN1 IN (" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("e607").Value & ")")
```

With this:

```
    Dim rng As Range, sSql As String
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("e607")
    Debug.Print "Range.Value = |" & rng.Value & "|"
    sSql = "SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLENAME (nolock) WHERE COLUMN1 IN (" & rng.Value & ")"
    Debug.Print "SQL = |" & sSql & "|"
    .CommandText = sSql
```

`Debug.Print` prints to the immediate window so you can double-check that the variables are holding what you expect them to. I like using `|` instead of `"` when debugging strings because I almost never have a `|` inside a string.

Also, I wouldn't bother using `Array()` for the `CommandText` or the `Connection`. I'd redo your first line to look something like this for readability.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI" _
                & ";Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=anglobisql" _
                & ";Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096" _
                & ";Workstation ID=MyIDHere;Use Encryption for Data=False" _
                & ";Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME" _
      , Destination:=Range("A1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by removing the array text so

```
.CommandText = Array("SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLENAME (nolock) WHERE ...
```

becomes

```
.CommandText = ("SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLENAME (nolock) WHERE ...
```